# Count vaules in Div and show recults in Span

Tags: html, jquery

So i have a list of cards that each have an ID that sets when the page loads (these are diffent each time), i want to be able to go through each of the cards and count how many times 'completed' appears in that card then show the value in the . The html is shown below userCoursesComplete span.

```html
<div class="col-4 mb-4" id="userCard3">
  <div class="card user-card shadow bg-white">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title text-grey-800">dave</h5>
      <p class="card-text">dave@test.co.uk</p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 1 - </p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 2 - </p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 3 - </p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 4 - completed 21/09/21</p>
      <p class="card-text">Courses Completed - <span class="userCoursesComplete">0</span></p><button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#userModal3" class="btn btn-link float-right">view user</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your jQuery code

Comment: Dont manipulate or read the values straight from html, use data attribute like this data-course-complete='x' . Later you can loop through the fields and count them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.userCoursesComplete').text(function() { 
  return $(this).closest(".card-body").find(".card-text.d-none:contains('completed')").length
})
```

This will search for div with classes `card-text d-none` that contains completed in the text and return the amount found. BUT I will recommend that you add a class to the div that has been completed and then count those.

**Demo**

```js
$('.userCoursesComplete').text(function() { 
  return $(this).closest(".card-body").find(".card-text.d-none:contains('completed')").length
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4 mb-4" id="userCard3">
  <div class="card user-card shadow bg-white">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title text-grey-800">dave</h5>
      <p class="card-text">dave@test.co.uk</p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 1 - </p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 2 - </p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 3 - </p>
      <p class="card-text d-none">Course 4 - completed 21/09/21</p>
      <p class="card-text">Courses Completed - <span class="userCoursesComplete">0</span></p><button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#userModal3" class="btn btn-link float-right">view user</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```